# EF Core Include method not working

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, devart

I recently updated to asp.net core 2.0. Since upgrading all my Linq queries using Include Method are failing, it is not translated properly to SQL.

For instance this:

```
var entities = helpTopicRepository.Entities.Include(x => x.HelpArticles).FirstOrDefault(t => topicIds.Any(a => a == t.Id));
```

is translated to:

```
SELECT x.HelpArticles.ART_ID, 
x.HelpArticles.AVAILABLE, 
x.HelpArticles.CONTENT, 
x.HelpArticles.DISPLAYORDER, 
x.HelpArticles.HELPFULNO, 
x.HelpArticles.HELPFULYES, 
x.HelpArticles.KEYWORDS, 
x.HelpArticles.TITLE, 
x.HelpArticles.TOPICID
FROM HELPARTICLE x.HelpArticles
```

which is results in the following error:

> ```
> Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00933: SQL
> ```
>
> command not properly ended    at Devart.Data.Oracle.ay.b()    at
>   Devart.Data.Oracle.am.f()    at Devart.Data.Oracle.am.e()    at
>   Devart.Data.Oracle.c5.a(am A_0, Int32 A_1)    at
>   Devart.Data.Oracle.c5.a(Int32 A_0, bg A_1)    at
>   Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleCommand.InternalExecute(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, IDisposable disposable, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords,
>   Boolean nonQuery)    at
>   Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, Boolean nonQuery)    at
>   Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.ai.a(CommandBehavior A_0)    at
>   Devart.Common.Entity.cj.d(CommandBehavior A_0)    at
>   Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.ai.b(CommandBehavior A_0)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection
>   connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2
>   parameterValues)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection
>   connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean
>   buffer)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryBuffer.IncludeCollection(Int32
>   includeId, INavigation navigation, INavigation inverseNavigation,
>   IEntityType targetEntityType, IClrCollectionAccessor
>   clrCollectionAccessor, IClrPropertySetter inverseClrPropertySetter,
>   Boolean tracking, Object entity, Func`1 relatedEntitiesFactory)    at
>   lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , Client , Object[] )    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.IncludeCompiler._Include[TEntity](QueryContext
>   queryContext, TEntity entity, Object[] included, Action`3 fixup)    at
>   lambda_method(Closure , Client )    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) 
>   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.b__0(QueryContext
>   qc) ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

I'm using Devart dotconnect to connect to Oracle database.

Comment: The same happens here, with recent update to .net core 2.0. Please, let me know your fix if you just got it.

Comment: It is a devart issue, they are working on a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug with using multiple .Include() in EF Core 2 is fixed. Look forward to the next public build of dotConnect for Oracle.

Comment: The new build of dotConnect for Oracle 9.5.399 is available for download: http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=36257.

Answer (score 1):

Is due to your statement:

```
var entities = helpTopicRepository.Entities.Include(x => x.HelpArticles).FirstOrDefault(t => topicIds.Any(a => a == t.Id));
```

Assuming that `topicIds` is a list, here is a fix:

```
var entities = helpTopicRepository.Entities
    .Include(x => x.HelpArticles)
    .Where(t => topicIds.Contains(t.Id))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This code is functionally equivalent to what the OP already had. Making these changes won't do anything to fix the problem.